# MASM assembly scanf format

Tags: assembly

so basically what i'm trying to do is create a calculator that takes an input like 3+2*3*4 and prints out the result. The issue i'm having might seem pretty simple (i'm pretty much a beginner in assembly) but I really can't figure out how to scanf a format such as "%d %c %d %c %d" without the console crashing. I don't want to scan it as a string because i built my calculator parser code around the fact that i can operate with the elements (i'd want to scan it in the '3','+','2','*','3','*,'4' format).

Cheers and a happy new year!

further edit: with jcomeau_ictx 's help I finally managed to make it work properly, but now i find myself in another pickle: my assignment states that input can vary from 2 operands to 4, and the code will only work for the dws of space i allocate for sir1, so in this scenario it always needs 4 operands to work. I can overpass this by inputting 0's and entering until it works, though.

```
.data
sir1 dd 0,0,0,0,0,0,0
rezultat db "rezultat= %d %c %d %c %d %c %d ",13,10, 0
format db "%d %c %d %c %d %c %d",0
msg1 DB "introduceti sirul: ",13,10, 0
.code
start:

push offset msg1
call printf
add ESP, 4

push offset sir1+24
push offset sir1+20
push offset sir1+16
push offset sir1+12
push offset sir1+8
push offset sir1+4
push offset sir1
push offset format
call scanf
add ESP, 32

push sir1+24
push sir1+20
push sir1+16
push sir1+12
push sir1+8
push sir1+4
push sir1
push offset rezultat
call printf
add ESP, 32

;apel functie exit
push 0
call exit
end star
```

t

Comment: Yes, the code is needed; please post it.

Comment: scanf is nearly a mini-interpreter. Easiest is to simply compile some C implementation to assembler, preferably a somewhat smaller, embedded version.

Comment: I don't really know how to do that, besides I'm not exactly a C expert, so I'd rather just stick to assembly.

Comment: does this code crash? and if so, does it give you an error message?

Comment: im compiling it in notepad++, it just crashes without any message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

two problems I see: (1) you're only allocating one byte of space to hold the results of the scanf, and (2) you're adding 16 to the stack after only pushing 8 bytes onto it.

this works:

```
jcomeau@aspire:/tmp$ as -o test.o test.asm
jcomeau@aspire:/tmp$ ld -o test -dynamic-linker /lib/ld-linux.so.2 /usr/lib32/crt1.o /usr/lib32/crti.o -lc test.o /usr/lib32/crtn.o
jcomeau@aspire:/tmp$ echo 23 + 24 | ./test
introduceti sirul: rezultat= 23 + 24
```

the code, in GNU as format:

```
.intel_syntax noprefix
.extern printf, scanf, exit
.data
numbers: .long 0, 0
sir1: .byte 0, 0
rezultat: .asciz "rezultat= %d %c %d\n"
format: .asciz "%d %c %d"
msg1: .asciz "introduceti sirul: "
.globl _start
.globl main
main:
push offset msg1
call printf
add ESP, 4

push offset numbers+4
push offset sir1
push offset numbers
push offset format
call scanf
add ESP, 16

push numbers+4
push sir1
push numbers
push offset rezultat
call printf
add ESP, 16

push 0
call exit
```

if you're going to continue calling library routines from assembly language, you'd do well to invest the time to study Agner Fog's resources, particularly #2, "Optimizing subroutines in assembly language", the section on calling conventions. http://www.agner.org/optimize/